# Rewrite rules - Just wanna know is it possible?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Example:

I want to make an url with different categorised variables. And there is an order. First variable is vegetables({variable01}), second is fruits({variable02}), third is trees ({variable03}) etc.

**xxx.com/{variable01}-{variable02}-{variable03}-{variable04}-......**

Yes I got this url.

**BUT**

What if a variable have two words(or three) AND I want the seperator is also a hyphen(brussels-sprouts)?

Example:

xxx.com/brussels-sprouts-{variable02}-{variable03}-{variable04}-......

or

xxx.com/{variable02}-green-apple-{variable03}-{variable04}-......

xxx.com/**brussels-sprouts**-*green-apple*

How can this be possible?

Thanks.

Comment: a CMS (Like `Drupal`) generates URLs for you, not `Apache`. by using `.htaccess` you can add rules to handle that URLs.

Comment: Igor thanks for your reply. I know it. Wordpress gives me pretty pretty urls. Thanks wordpress.

But wordpress use / I want -

I'm rewriting wordpress url structure.

It is possible to make xxx.com/brussels-sprouts/green-apple
but I want xxx.com/brussels-sprouts-green-apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to specify the boundaries of your variables anymore, so it's only possible if you know the exact amount of variables and only 1 of your variables may contain hyphens. You can create a regex for that:

First variable:

```
^([\w-]+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)$
```

Second variable:

```
^(\w+)-([\w-]+)-(\w+)-(\w+)$
```

**But:** if you know that each variable can have at most 1 hyphen, you can also do this:

/var1-foo1-var2-foo2-var3-foo3-var4

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+(-\w+)?)-(\w+(-\w+)?)-(\w+(-\w+)?)-(\w+(-\w+)?)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$3&var3=$5&var4=$7 [L]
```

Which results in:

```
array (
    'var1' => 'var1-foo1',
    'var2' => 'var2-foo2',
    'var3' => 'var3-foo3',
    'var4' => 'var4',
)
```

Comment: That was close. But that variables maybe have 3 hyphens or more sometimes. Too difficult to handle all of this. But that is wanted from me. Also one more step all urls must have and end text :D

xxx.com/brussels-sprouts-green-apple-{variable03}-{variable04}-...-uncle-joe

-uncle-joe has a hyphen and is the last part of all generate urls. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, same principle, just append the same regex part to the end, even if you don't need it as a variable.

Comment: I suggest to use / as a variable separator in your case, unless you have specific reasons not to do so?